# C# datagrid bindingsource null exception error

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, datagridview

I have been working on an application to update data in a database from a datagridviewer. The issue I am running into here is that after I change a row, I try to refill the data adapter so I am able to see a refreshed view of the database. However, when I try that, I always get an error on the BindingSource_PositionChanged event. I'm assuming it's because I am flushing out what it was bound to and doesn't know what to do. Is there any way around this so I can refresh the data grid but not get the error?

I attached a screenshot of the error.[image]

Code Below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace SBTForceClose
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void LoadGrid()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet1.LKP_SBT_FORCE_CLOSE;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dataSet1.LKP_SBT_FORCE_CLOSE' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.lKP_SBT_FORCE_CLOSETableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.LKP_SBT_FORCE_CLOSE);

    }

    //Initialize variables for all columns.

    Int32 VAL1;
    Int32 VAL2;
    string VAL3 = "";
    Int32 VAL4;
    DateTime VAL5;
    DateTime VAL6;
    Int32 VAL7;
    Int32 VAL8;
    string VAL9 = "";
    string VAL10 = "";
    string VAL11 = "";
    DateTime VAL12;
    string VAL13 ="";
    DateTime VAL14;
    DateTime VAL15;
    string VAL16 ="";
    string VAL17 ="";
    string VAL18 ="";
    string VAL19 ="";
    string VAL20 ="";

    private DataRow LastDataRow = null;

    private void UpdateRowToDatabase()
    {
        if (LastDataRow!=null)
        {
            if (LastDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("This row has been changed. Are you sure you would like to update this record?", "!Record Changed!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    //GET ALL COLUMN DATA FOR CURRENT ROW SELECTED. AT THIS POINT WE KNOW IT'S BEEN MODIFIED.
                    dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
                    VAL1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    VAL2 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    VAL3 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    VAL4 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                    VAL5 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                    VAL6 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                    VAL7 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                    VAL8 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                    VAL9 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                    VAL10 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                    VAL11 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                    VAL12 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString());
                    VAL13 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                    VAL14 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString());
                    VAL15 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString());
                    VAL16 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
                    VAL17 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString();
                    VAL18 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value.ToString();
                    VAL19 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[18].Value.ToString();
                    VAL20 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[19].Value.ToString();

                    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
                    conn.ConnectionString = "MyConnString";
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    try
                    {

                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE LKP_SBT_FORCE_CLOSE SET VENDOR_NUMBER = ?, VENDOR_DESC = ?, STORE_NUMBER = ?, EFFECTIVE_START_DATE = ?, FORCE_CLOSE_DATE = ?, CATEGORY_NUMBER = ?, CATEGORY_ID = ?, IS_ALL_STORES = ?, IS_CATEGORY_CLOSE = ?, CURRENT_FLAG = ?, EXTRACT_DATE = ?, SOURCE_TABLE_NAME = ?, CREATE_DATE = ?, MAINT_DATE = ?, CREATE_UID = ?, MAINT_UID = ?, DELETE_FLAG = ?, DELETE_UID = ? WHERE FORCE_CLOSE_SCHED_ID = ?";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL2", VAL2);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL3", VAL3);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL4", VAL4);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL5", VAL5);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL6", VAL6);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL7", VAL7);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL8", VAL8);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL9", VAL9);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL10", VAL10);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL11", VAL11);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL12", VAL12);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL13", VAL13);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL14", VAL14);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL15", VAL15);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL16", VAL16);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL17", VAL17);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL18", VAL18);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL19", VAL19);
                        //   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL20", VAL20);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL1", VAL1);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void lKPSBTFORCECLOSEBindingSource_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Once a row has been updated and I try to fill the table adapter again, I get an error here saying it's not set to an instance of an object.
        BindingSource thisBindingSource = (BindingSource)sender;
        DataRow thisDataRow = ((DataRowView)thisBindingSource.Current).Row;
        if (thisDataRow==LastDataRow)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Something went wrong!");
        }
        UpdateRowToDatabase();
        LastDataRow = thisDataRow;

    }

    private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I try to get a refreshed list from the database for the grid once we update a row. I originally had this right after the query execution and it failed.
        // I Decided to try it here but it still fails.
        this.lKP_SBT_FORCE_CLOSETableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.LKP_SBT_FORCE_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The binding source doesn't seem to have any items.

> [BindingSource.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> An Object that represents the current item in the underlying list
>   represented by the List property, or **null if the list has no items**.

Comment: How would I refresh the datagridview again after updating the table?